# Platanus_allee genome assembler failed assebly error

Tags: bioinformatics, genome

I am trying to run Platanus_allee genome assembler to assemble a genome. However, when I run phase command, it gives the following error:

**My command:**

> bio@bio-XPS-8700:~/Fareeha/Platanus/Platanus_allee_v2.0.2_Linux_x86_64$ ./platanus_allee phase -c out_contig.fa out_junctionKmer.fa \platanus_allee phase \ -c out_contig.fa out_junctionKmer.fa \ -IP1 /home/bio/Fareeha/test/SMIX_test_data/Unzip/SDNA-270_1_head-3000000.fq /home/bio/Fareeha/test/SMIX_test_data/Unzip/SDNA-270_2_head-3000000.fq \ 2>phase.log

**Output :**

platanus_allee version: 2.0.2

./platanus_allee phase -c out_contig.fa out_junctionKmer.fa platanus_allee phase -c out_contig.fa out_junctionKmer.fa -IP1 /home/bio/Fareeha/test/SMIX_test_data/Unzip/SDNA-270_1_head-3000000.fq /home/bio/Fareeha/test/SMIX_test_data/Unzip/SDNA-270_2_head-3000000.fq 2

> ```
> Error(13): Error, SolveDBG exception!! 
> platanus_allee solve_DBG command failed.
> ```

Can anyone please help me solve it ?

Comment: This isn't [tag:assembly] language.  I'm not sure it's sequence-alignment either, please remove that tag if it doesn't apply.  Also, [tag:error-handling] is for questions about how to write error-handling code in programs, not how to interpret error messages from programs you're not writing

Answer (score 0):

In the phase stage of platanus2 I have solved it by installing minimap2 with conda and everything should work.

```
conda install -c bioconda minimap2
```